# Args argument to storybook template is wrong shape

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to follow https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction and hitting a snag when trying to do the `Template` example. My code is:

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface FooProps {
  myArg: string;
}

const Foo: FC<FooProps> = ({ myArg }) => <p>{myArg}</p>;
Foo.displayName = 'Foo';

export default {
  component: Foo,
  title: 'Foo',
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Foo>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Foo> = (args) => {
  console.log(args);
  return <Foo {...args} />;
};

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = { myArg: 'Foo' };
```

However, the `args` argument that's passed to `Template` is a complex object that describes the story and has nested under it `args.args` which is what I'd want to pass to my component. Trying to use that throws a TS error though, but also from looking at the docs and GH issues, it seems like people are successfully using this paradigm, so I'm not sure why it's failing for me.

I'm using the latest storybook version that's been released (`6.5.13`), and my configuration is:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    './**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because we had `passArgsFirst: false` in our `.storybook/preview.js` configuration file, as a previous developer had added this when upgrading from v5 to v6 even though it was unnecessary at the time, was just being overly cautious.

Removing that from our configuration fixed the above problem, and now we can write stories following the example that storybook docs gives.

See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#args-passed-as-first-argument-to-story for more information.